# Calculate pixels between two points on a image

Tags: android, iphone, algorithm, pixel

Turns out I am not explaining what I want to do very well so I am going to re-write the whole question again and add graphics to assist in the explanation.

I am designing an app for android/iPhone. I have designed one algorithm for it already, but am stuck on the next one. What I am aiming to do is place two horizontal lines on an image (any image, just a picture taken by the iPhone/android) and then calculate what pixel the lines lye on, to then calculate the number of pixels between them. 
I.e. 
Take this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/41vS1.png

Then place two horizontal lines anywhere on the image, like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne4tV.png

What I want to calculate is the value of y, or how many vertical pixels are between the two lines. To do this I must know what pixel the two lines lye on.
Assuming that the horizontal lines are both only 1 pixel in height what would I use to work out what pixel in the image the line lies on. I.e. what is the value of the y-intercept(y=mx+c), or c, on each of the horizontal lines.
To explain what I mean further, lets assume that an image is a graph. Each pixel equals a value of 1, so for an image with a resolution of 1920x2560 the maximum value of the y-axis would be 1920 and the maximum of the x-axis would be 2560. How would I design an algorithm to calculate what the y-intercept of both lines are?

Comment: @alextsc , nothing so far... I have developed an algorithm to calculate the height(m) based on # of pixels and the distance from the object that you are calculating the height from. I am just lost on how to calculate pixels in an image, besides reading the metadata for the height and width in pixels of the whole image.

Comment: Are you searching for Pythagoras formula? ;) distance is √(height^2+width^2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distance between two points (Pythagora):

```
dx = x1 - x2;
dy = y1 - y2;

dist = sqrt (dx*dx + dy*dy);
```

Distance between two horizontal lines:

```
d = y1 - y2;
```

If your lines are defined as `y1 = k1x + n1` and `y2 = k2x + n2`, then (they're horizontal, `k1` and `k2` are 0) the distance between them is `n2 - n1`.

**EDIT:** ok, after you edited your question it makes a bit more sense now. But still: since you (or user) is adding the lines, your code always *knows* where they lie. Their end coordinates would be:

line1: {(0,y1):(picture.width,y1)}
line2: {(0,y2):(picture.width,y2)}
distance: |y2-y1|

Since they're both horizontal they ofcourse never cross.

You should just keep a reference to y1 and y2 (from the line-placing code) in an appropriate space. Since your question is for Android and iOS the answer is: in that part of code that would correspond to `model` in MVC.

Comment: I just edited my question, this answers the second part of my question, which I could of worked out anyway but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Vigi: your question is still not very clear. Are you looking for a graphical algorithm that scannes the image and finds these two lines?

Comment: Ok, I re-worded my question, maybe it makes more sense now?

Comment: @Vigi: yes, it makes more sense now, +1 for that. I'll edit my answer but i'm affraid already know all that is added.

Comment: @Vigi: so the subquestion would be: how exactly are you placing those horizontal lines? Are they placed in code somehow or are they _already on the picture_?

Comment: Yeah they are placed in code, cheers for that. I guess I should of thought about it a bit more before I asked the question.

Comment: @Vigi: no problem, happens to anyone :)