# android how many pixels between 2 points

Tags: android, point

i want to calculate how many pixels there are between 2 points on my screen.

I've seen that i can draw a straight line between 2 points using Path class, but i don't really want to draw that line, i only want to know how long is it in pixels..

i really need it for my MapView clusters implementation..

i can get each marker position on screen with no problem, but don't know how to calculate pixel's "distance" between them ... 
i know that there are cluster's implementations available but i want to try and create one of my own

help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Ever heard of Pythagoras? `d=sqrt(pow(x1-x2,2)+pow(y1-y2,2))`

Comment: This may [help][1] you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598867/calculate-pixels-between-two-points-on-a-image


check this out

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is very straightforward using a bit of algebra :)

Take the co-ordinates of both points and calculate the difference between their x and y values e.g.

```
dx = p1.x - p2.x;
dy = p1.y - p2.y;

distance = Math.sqrt( (dx * dx) + (dy * dy) );
```

Where `p1` and `p2` are the points you want get find the distance between, and `distance` is the result. It will be a double but you can round it to the nearest `int` if you wish

Comment: silly me... :) you're right i didn't thought about it that way